# Why is Bitlocker missing from Control Panel?

Tags: windows-vista, bitlocker

I have a Dell Latitude Vista Ultimate Laptop that has Bitlocker installed on it and now I want to change the way it is set up. The trouble is that the BitLocker item in control panel is missing. All the docs on the web say it should be under the Security section of control panel, but it is definatly not there.

Does anyone know what may have caused this and how I can get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having got no where with resolving the Bitlocker issue I decided to install [Vista Service Pack 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd262148.aspx). After installing this the Icon has reappeard.

Answer (score 1):

A TPM module is required to turn on Bitlocker. Also, your hard drive needs to be partitioned a certain way before Bitlocker will work.

To see what is missing, type "Bitlocker" in the Start menu search box and click on "Bitlocker Drive Encryption".

Comment: I have a TPM and checked it is enabled, the hard disks are partitioned. I even have BitLocker installed, running and the hard disk encrypted. It is just the control panel applet that is missing.

Comment: Make sure you are trying to access Bitlocker from the following path Control Panel\Security\BitLocker Drive Encryption . Bitlocker is also visible from the Classic View.

You can try to enable the advanced startup options by following these instructions: http://www.petri.co.il/enable-bitlocker-encryption-vista.htm

Comment: Actually, you can enable Bitlocker without a TPM: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4681-bitlocker-drive-encryption-windows-7-drive-turn-off-no-tpm.html